# OnCollisionEnter() not working, how i can fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make random generator and me need destroy object if it touch myself or house, i give colliders to objects.

`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Structure") // this is tree
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Floor") // this is details of house
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using static System.Random;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Игровые объекты")] // game object 
    public GameObject Tree;

    [Header("Лимит строений")] // limit for building
    public int StuctLimit;

    [Header("Рандомные координаты")] // random position
    public int randomPosX;
    public int randomPosZ;

    private void Generating()
    {
        if(StuctLimit == 0)
        {
            System.Random randomPos = new System.Random();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 1500; i++)
            {
                randomPosX = randomPos.Next(10, 290);
                randomPosZ = randomPos.Next(10, 290);

                Instantiate(Tree, new Vector3(randomPosX, 0.0f, randomPosZ), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            StuctLimit++;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Generating();
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HouseGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Строение дома")] // game object
    public GameObject House;

    [Header("Лимит строений")] // limit for building
    public int StuctLimit;

    [Header("Рандомные координаты")] // random position
    public int randomPosX;
    public int randomPosZ;

    private void Generating() 
    {
        if(StuctLimit == 0)
        {
            System.Random randomPos = new System.Random();

            for (int time = 0; time <= 20; time++)
            {
                randomPosX = randomPos.Next(10, 290);
                randomPosZ = randomPos.Next(10, 290);

                Instantiate(House, new Vector3(randomPosX, 0.5f, randomPosZ), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            StuctLimit++;     
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Generating();
    }
}
```

It was worked, but i round position for set block, i use it(Mathf.Round(range))

I use Instantiate(Object, new Vector3(positions), Quaternion.identity) for create structure

Here code for: Check Touch objects; Generating Trees; Generating House.

Comment: What is exactly what is not working? Collision detection?

Comment: Yes, i testing it, i add code for write in console, but no thing

Comment: Sorry for my english =)

Comment: No prob :). Make sure you all the requirements in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) for the collision detection and that your gameObjects and colliders are enbled. (`Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached`)

Comment: try... What you thing about my code

Comment: If you changes the position not use rigidbody it may not also register collision

Comment: Don't work, colliders are enabled on scene and prefabs

Comment: I spawn tree and house and check collision for touch with myself and house

Comment: It used to work, I add Mathf.Round() to build script and don't work now =(, i try off build script.

Comment: In your `OnCollisionEnter` you are checking against the `collision.gameObject.name`. The name of objects instantiated at run-time often have numbers appended to their names ( e.g.: "Structure (1)"). Check if your condition is met and if not make it more fail-proof (e.g.: use `string.Contains() ` or check something like the layer each object belongs to)